# Visual Studio 2008 not showing member values of structure pointer

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I'm writing C code and sometimes when debugging, Visual Studio 2008 will not display any data when I hover over certain variables.  It seems random, and although it's seldom, I'm in a tough spot when it does happen.

Does anyone know how to fix or avoid this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you add the variable declaration for the variable that you're attempting to debug?

Comment: Are you debugging a release version? Maybe Visual Studio optimized your variable(s) away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this twice now.  Both times it was a matter of straightening out include statements where structures were including other structures.  Everything was technically correct but I guess Visual just got confused.  See where you are including the structure Visual can't debug and try to arrange things so that it is only included directly in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue.
I am quite sure that Visual Assist X is to blame, I never had this issue for 5 years before installing VA X last week.

So I suggest these three options:

1. File an issue report to VA X devs.
2. Disable (temporarily) or uninstall VA X.
3. Create a watch for every single value you want to have a look at -- very annying indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating your Intellisense file. Close VS2008 and delete the .ncb file.

Comment: Thank you Soo Wei but that did not help.  The same variable will not display.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm out of ideas... this only happens during debugging?

BTW I use Visual Assist on top of VS2005 and it augments the standard Intellisense very well.

Comment: I just got another clue.  When I added a watch on the variable and hovered over the value, it said "The value for this item is stale due to a problem that occurred while evaluating it.  Hover your cursor over the refresh button for details."  So my next question is, where is the refresh button?  Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, it's the little button to the right of the 'Value' box.  Didn't notice it...

Comment: Wait, that's only when it's out of scope of the routine I'm looking at.  My original question remains the same.